# Where to search for PhD level jobs in OR?

Tags: job-market, phd

I started hunting for jobs and I'm not sure what are good websites I should be keeping an eye on. 
I'm interested mainly in Europe.

Comment: Regardless of full time or internship, I think the answer to this question can help: [How to find an internship in OR/Optimization?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/how-to-find-an-internship-in-or-optimization)

Comment: If you are interested in optimization, you might try Opt-Net, which is Eurocentric. I put a link to it in an answer to the question linked in Ehsan's comment.

Comment: Why Oregon? ${}{}$

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I work as an optimization specialist in a large utility company in Denmark.

- Look for "Data Scientist", "Data Engineer", "Optimization specialist", "Operations Research Specialist" or other variations. Examples can be see [here](https://careers.vattenfall.com/jobs/optimization-specialist/) and [here](https://www.amazon.jobs/en/jobs/898834/ops-research-analyst?ss=paid&utm_campaign=cxro&utm_content=job_posting&utm_medium=social_media&utm_source=linkedin.com).
- However, the problem is that many businesses do not know about optimization and how it can benefit them **even if they are using it**. Therefore try to find the optimization specialists in companies and reach out directly to find out where the best part to apply is. Of course this works best the clearer you know what company you want to work for.
- There are not many "pure" OR jobs going around. In most cases, it also include data analysis and "science", as well as software and tool development (i.e. putting your stuff into production). So if you have a "standard" OR degree, I would suggest for you to create competencies in those areas, apply for a "Data Scientist" position and then find your OR niche there.

Answer (score 6):

The INFORMS Career Centre may be a good starting point

https://careercenter.informs.org/jobs

Good luck in your search!

Comment: I've gone through it, but it has very few jobs in Europe, it's mainly US and China for some reason

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in PhD-level research jobs in Europe, you might regularly check [EURAXES](https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu). In addition, mailing lists of different societies or groups are great for learning about new positions as well as upcoming CfPs, seminars, and workshops. One example is [DMANET](https://www.zaik.uni-koeln.de/mailman/listinfo/dmanet).

Comment: Thanks! Euraxes looks like a good source

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking about working in the UK, [indeed.co.uk](https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Operations+Research&l=) might be useful for preliminary searching.

As you ask for PhD level jobs, [this](https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Operations%20Research&vjk=3732830d1c9c0da3) and [this](https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Operations%20Research&vjk=14df46094d368d58) (both Operational Research Scientists) are good examples; a key requirement being "PhD in operations research, mathematics, ..."

Good luck.